# Need to pass variable to a batch script from a perl script

Tags: perl, batch-file

I'm running a perl script, which in turn calls a batch script. I need  to pass 3 parameters to the batch script. I'm passing the parameters, since it it easier to read a file in perl script & capture the desired value. But, my script is erroring out with error - 'The system cannot find the path specified.'
I'm using below code --

```
while (<FILE>) 
{
    ($file, $rcc, $loc) = split(',');
    my @lines = qx/"D:\\SiebelAdmin\\Commands\\WinFile_Move.bat $file $rcc $loc" /;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your parameter is not what you expected. Possible empty lines in your file?

Comment: I checked the parameter by printing the value. Values are as expected --
file=XLNXlogin.css
 rcc=$/Compass/CodeFreeze/SIEBEL/2015_NOV/NGCM-II/ServerFiles/CSS,
 loc=D:\sba81\SWEApp\PUBLIC\enu\files\custom<br>
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes. With them, the system interprets the whole line as a command, not as a command with parameters.

```
my @lines = qx/D:\\SiebelAdmin\\Commands\\WinFile_Move.bat $file $rcc $loc/;
```

Comment: After removing the double quotes, am getting Parse Error. No other error is there. <code>file=XLNXlogin.css
 rcc=$/Compass/CodeFreeze/SIEBEL/2015_NOV/NGCM-II/ServerFiles/CSS
 loc=D:\sba81\SWEApp\PUBLIC\enu\files\custom
Parse Error
Parse Error</code>

Comment: @parthodas: Can you run the command from the command line with the given arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works for you.
I have created sample batch script which takes two args and print it on prompt.
This script location is on desktop.

## Code of batch script

```
@echo off
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
shift
shift

echo %arg1%
echo %arg2%
```

## Output of batch script

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>a.bat perl5.8 perl5.18
perl5.8
perl5.18
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

Now I have created the perl script which calls this batch script. This perl script is present in C drive.

## Code for perl script

```
my $bat_file = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\a.bat';
my $arg1 = 'perl5.8';
my $arg2 = 'perl5.18';
my @lines = `$bat_file $arg1 $arg2`;
print @lines;
```

## Output of perl script

```
C:\>perl tmp.pl
perl5.8
perl5.18
```

Comment: When trying your codes on my local machine, it is working fine. Then, I tried implementing the same in my script with below modifications. But again I'm getting the same Parse Error.  `my $bat_file='D:\\SiebelAdmin\\Commands\\WinFile_Move.bat';
  my $mydir='D:\SiebelAdmin\CR_Files\CR117365_20150831_0254\CSS';
  my $file='XLNXlogin.css';
  my $loc='D:\SiebelAdmin\Commands\WinFile_Move.bat';
  printf "file=$file\nmydir=$mydir\nloc=$loc\n$bat_file\n";
  my @lines = \`$bat_file $mydir $file $loc\`;`

Comment: @parthodas - Can you please copy entire error string and post it? Trying to understand which is giving error - perl script or batch script? Also, the code you posted above shows '$bat_file' and '$loc' is referring to same file.  Is this correct also?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Found the error. The perl script is fine. The batch script is giving the error. Removed few parameter declaration from the batch script and now Parse Error is gone. Now the error has changed. I've checked the Environment Variable for PATH and it is set properly. Please let me know if you want to see the batch script. It is now throwing --
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

**Perl file:**

```
my $arg = "hey";
my $bat_file_loc = "C:\\abc.bat";
system($bat_file_loc,$arg);
```

**Batch file:**

```
set arg1=%1
```